# Short writing the iterate loop in one line

Tags: python, directory, path

can you please tell me how to shorten the writing of the iterating loop in one line without writing **join(path, name)** twice? Maybe it can be implemented through lambda? Does my example calculate the path twice? Thanks

```
import os
from os.path import exists, join

path = r"C:\Test_folder\\"
name_list = ["image01.png", "image02.png", "image03.png"]
result = [join(path, name) for name in name_list if exists(join(path, name))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code does evaluate `join(path, name)` twice per iteration.

If you insist on using a list comprehension and using Python >= 3.8 you can use an [assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/):

```py
result = [p for name in name_list if exists(p := join(path, name))]
```

This evaluates `join(path, name)` once per iteration, assigns its return value to `p` and evaluates `exists(p)`, then if it's true it is being added to the resulting list.

This is roughly equivalent to

```py
result = []
for name in name_list:
    p = join(path, name)
    if exists(p):
        result.append(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [abs_path for abs_path in [join(path, name) for name in name_list] if exists(abs_path)]
```

It can be made as two lines:

```
abs_pathes = [join(path, name) for name in name_list]
result = [abs_path for abs_path in abs_pathes if exists(abs_path)]
```

So, it is not nested.

Comment: How did that become a nested loop ??

Comment: @DeepSpace it is not nested. It is two sequential loops writen in one line.

Comment: Hence they are nested

Comment: matrix = [[j for j in range(5)] for i in range(5)] - this is nested, my is not. Nested means you have a loop inside the body of other loop.

Comment: The `for abs_path` loop is running for every `name` in the `for name in name_list`. This is nested loops...

Comment: Nested loop by definition is a loop inside the other loop. I wrote this one line structure as two lines to show that there is no one loop inside the other. Be a shame.

Comment: @DeepSpace I actually googled "nested loops" now, and all I saw disagrees with you. Can you link to any definition of "nested loops" that agrees with you?

Comment: @Guy Can *you*? (See previous comment)

Comment: The fist [link](https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/csawesome/Unit4-Iteration/topic-4-4-nested-loops.html) google shows. There is a picture and definition.

Comment: I think it's _not_ nested looping. this code simply maps/filters a list twice. it does *not* exhibit quadratic behavior. -- the only, marginal, improvement I can think of is to use a generator for the inside expression instead of actually constructing the list. the other answer uses the `:=` operator gainfully so that's good to see.

Comment: This is the weakness of list comprehension. It is difficult to read them even for experienced persons.